# Mostrar o cabeçalho da tabela a cada nova linha da tabela

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Eu estou gerando uma tabela usando php e bootsstrap, a cada nova linha da tabela, quero mostrar o cabeçalho da tabela novamente para não confundir as informações, segue o código da tabela e do cabeçalho:

Cabeçalho :

```
<table class='table table-striped'>
<tr>
 <th>Editar</th>
 <th>ID</th>
 <th>Tipo</th>
 <th>Entrada em milímetros</th>
 <th>Saída em milímetros</th>
 <th>Tamanho F</th>
 <th>Tamanho M</th>
 <th>Tamanho G</th>
 <th>Tamanho GG</th>
 <th>Foto do aparelho</th>
 <th>Foto do acabamento</th>
 <th>Foto Maquina</th>
 <th>Foto Maquina</th>
```

Tabela:

```
        print "<tr>";
         print "<td><button id='editarTamanho'name='editarTamanho' value='".$id_tamanho."' type='submit' class='btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'><strong>Editar<strong></button></td>";
         print "<td>".$id_tamanho."</td>";
         print "<td>".$resultado_nome_componente[0]."</td>";
         print "<td>".$entrada."</td>";
         print "<td>".$saida."</td>";
         print "<td>".$f."</td>";
         print "<td>".$m."</td>";
         print "<td>".$g."</td>";
         print "<td>".$gg."</td>";
         print "<td><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($foto_aparelho)."' height='150' width='150' alt=''></td>";
         print "<td><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($foto_acabamento)."' height='150' width='150' alt=''></td>";
         print "<td><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($foto_maquina1)."' height='150' width='150' alt=''></td>";
         print "<td><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($foto_maquina2)."' height='150' width='150' alt=''></td>";
        print "</tr>";
```

Oque eu preciso:

```
 Cabeçalho-------------------------------------------
 Dados-----------------------------------------------
 Cabeçalho-------------------------------------------
 Dados-----------------------------------------------
 Cabeçalho-------------------------------------------
 Dados-----------------------------------------------
```

E assim sucessivamente.

Answer (score 0):

O tabela e as linhas serão colocadas em um laço (for, while)?
Caso seja o cabeçalho pode ser uma linha dentro da tag . Logo abaixo você adicionará outra linha que será a tabela dentro das tag .

sendo mais ou menos assim:

```
<table class='table table-striped'>
```

```
?>
<tr>
 <th>Editar</th>
 <th>ID</th>
 <th>Tipo</th>
 <th>Entrada em milímetros</th>
 <th>Saída em milímetros</th>
 <th>Tamanho F</th>
 <th>Tamanho M</th>
 <th>Tamanho G</th>
 <th>Tamanho GG</th>
 <th>Foto do aparelho</th>
 <th>Foto do acabamento</th>
 <th>Foto Maquina</th>
 <th>Foto Maquina</th>
</tr>

print "<tr>";
print "<td><button id='editarTamanho'name='editarTamanho' value='".$id_tamanho."' type='submit' class='btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'><strong>Editar<strong></button></td>";
print "<td>".$id_tamanho."</td>";
print "<td>".$resultado_nome_componente[0]."</td>";
print "<td>".$entrada."</td>";
print "<td>".$saida."</td>";
print "<td>".$f."</td>";
print "<td>".$m."</td>";
print "<td>".$g."</td>";
print "<td>".$gg."</td>";
print "<td><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($foto_aparelho)."' height='150' width='150' alt=''></td>";
print "<td><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($foto_acabamento)."' height='150' width='150' alt=''></td>";
print "<td><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($foto_maquina1)."' height='150' width='150' alt=''></td>";
print "<td><img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($foto_maquina2)."' height='150' width='150' alt=''></td>";
print "</tr>";
<?php
}
```